# Problems with fgets() in C

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to store two characters in two different chars using fgets().

```
char tobereplaced[1], replacedwith[1];
printf("Please enter character to be replaced\n");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(tobereplaced, 2, stdin);
printf("Please enter character to replace with\n");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(replacedwith, 2, stdin);
printf("User asks to replace \'%s\' with \'%s\'\n", tobereplaced, replacedwith);
```

If i enter 'a' and 'b' I get the following output:

`User asks to replace '' with 'b'`

So my question is why is only the second value getting stored and the first one isnt?

Note, I am using "2" as the second argument in fgets() because if I use "1" (which to me seems like the obvious value) it doesnt stop and wait for input for some reason.

Comment: Are you aware that `tobereplaced[1]` can hold a strong of maximum length of zero? You need one more char for the NUL string terminator

Comment: Ah okay, then how come replacedwith manages to print its value?

Comment: It's called _undefined behaviour_. You call `fgets(tobereplaced, 2, stdin)` then `tobereplaced` must be of length 2 at least instead of 1. There is also another issue: `fgets` stores the end of line character (`\n`)  at the end of the string. And BTW `fflush(stdin)` is also undefined behaviour

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot, changing the length to 2 solved the problem.

Comment: There are *some* occasions when declaring an array of size `[1]` is useful, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Regarding the fflush(stdin). If i remove them the fgets wont stop and wait for input. How can I solve this problem without using the fflush? Or am I missing something crucial here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets()` attempts to read a *line* of input (all characters up to and including a `'\n'`).  Then it appends a *null character*.

With input <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, `fgets()` would like at least a `tobereplaced[3]` array to store store the `'a'`, `'\n'`, `'\0'`,

The following code is *bad* as it incorrectly told `fgets()` there was 2 `char` available in `tobereplaced[]`

```
char tobereplaced[1];           // Only 1
fgets(tobereplaced, 2, stdin);  // bad, UB, said it was 2
```

Instead, to read a line, with extra space in case the user enters some extra characters:

```
char tobereplaced[80];
fgets(tobereplaced, sizeof tobereplaced, stdin);

printf("Please enter character to replace with\n");
char replacedwith[80];
fgets(tobereplaced, sizeof tobereplaced, stdin);

printf("User asks to replace \'%c\' with \'%c\'\n", tobereplaced[0], replacedwith[0]);
```

---

> Regarding the `fflush(stdin)`. If I remove then the `fgets` won't stop and wait for input. How can I solve this problem without using the `fflush`? Or am I missing something crucial here?

Certainly due to using a prior `scanf()` which left a `'\n'` in `stdin`.  `fgets()` did not have to stop and wait for input as there was left-over `'\n'` in `stdin` to be read.  `fflush(stdin)` is *undefined behavior*.

I recommend to use only `fgets()` for user input.
Do not use `scanf()` until you understand why its bad.

Answer (score 0):

The function `fgets` stores a C string, witch is terminated by a null char, or `'\0'`, you need space to store this char or it will work unexpectedly. In your case, simply change the array size to 2 or use a function like `getchar()`.